# How to resolve "cannot pipe" issue with testcafe-hammerhead

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When running tests, I'm getting the following error:

```
1 Unhandled promise rejection:

  Error: Cannot pipe, not readable
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
  at ServerResponse.pipe (node:_http_outgoing:1070:22)
  at respondOnWebSocket (D:\e2e\0.0.157\node_modules\testcafe\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\websocket.js:56:9)
  at Array.decideOnProcessingStrategy (D:\e2e\0.0.157\node_modules\testcafe\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\stages.js:77:48)
  at run (D:\e2e\0.0.157\node_modules\testcafe\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\index.js:20:34)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

See future updates related to this issue in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7248).